# Auto-Populate Wallet Address in Input Field After Connecting Phantom Wallet with Solana Adapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, javascript, react

I'm working on a React project utilizing the Solana wallet adapter and encountering an issue with automatically filling in the user's wallet address into an input field upon connecting their Phantom wallet. Despite the wallet connection being successful, the input field intended to display the public wallet address remains empty.

Here's a snippet of my approach:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (wallet.connected) {
    setWalletAddress(wallet.publicKey?.toString() || '');
  }
}, [wallet.connected, wallet.publicKey]);
```

I expected the input field to automatically update with the user's wallet address once the connection is established, but this isn't happening. The rest of the application recognizes the wallet connection without issue.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge or can offer insights into what might be missing or incorrect in my implementation? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Steps to Reproduce:

Visit our application. --> [React App](https://submit.dedz.xyz/react/)

Initiate the wallet connection by selecting the "Connect Wallet" button.

Choose the Phantom Wallet from the options and authenticate the connection.

You can access the entire code from the link.
[React Code](https://codeshare.io/pA0y46)

Technical Details:

- React version: [18.2.0]
- @solana/wallet-adapter-react version: [0.15.35]
- Browser(s): [Chrome, Firefox]
- Wallet Used: Phantom